# Detect if HTTP request is from browser / Flex asynchronous request?

Tags: ajax, apache-flex

When Flex application make an asynchronus HTTP request, does it add a special header to the request, like some JavaScript framework does? Something that indicates whether this request is an AJAX call/not.

I just want my server side code to return different response format, depending on whether the request is made from browser/flex.

Regards, Andree.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can add your own [headers](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#headers). Maybe a better solution is to customize the request (add a parameter to distinguish between requests).